# Как перевести двумерный список строк в двумерный список чисел?

Tags: python, list

Имеется список:

```
lst = [['2', '3', '5'], ['8', '43', '3'], ['2', '1234', '12']]
```

Как привести данный список к такому состоянию, что каждый элемент списка в двумерном списке должен будет являться числом?

Comment: Так? `[[int(j) for j in i] for i in lst]`

Comment: И вы, по-моему, путаете список с массивом. Массивов в питоне нет (вернее есть, но в сторонних библиотеках). Термин "лист" не употребляется, говорят — список.

Comment: Помогло, насчёт лист и список не знал, только начинаю изучать python, начинал с java

Comment: Этот инструмент, кстати, называется списковым включением. Очень полезная вещь, советую про него почитать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот первый вариант:

```
list = [['2', '3', '5'], ['8', '43', '3'], ['2', '1234', '12']]
result = []
for sublist in list:
  subresult = []
  for string in sublist:
    subresult.append(int(string))
  result.append(sublist)
print(result) # [[2, 3, 5], [8, 43, 3], [2, 1234, 12]]
```

Вы также модете использовать вместо `int` `float` чтобы дробные тоже из строк преобразовывались

Вот вариант с генератором списка:

```
list = [['2', '3', '5'], ['8', '43', '3'], ['2', '1234', '12']]
result = [[int(string) for string in sublist] for sublist in list]
print(result) # [[2, 3, 5], [8, 43, 3], [2, 1234, 12]]
```

И еще бонус если вам надо все в один список с помощью генератора списков то можно так:

```
list = [['2', '3', '5'], ['8', '43', '3'], ['2', '1234', '12']]
result = [int(string) for sublist in list for string in sublist]
print(result) # [2, 3, 5, 8, 43, 3, 2, 1234, 12]
```

Ну а с вложенными циклами `for` все понятно (просто сразу в результирующий список добавлять)

Comment: В вопросе написано "каждый элемент массива в **двумерном** массиве должен будет являться числом". Так что в один список не нужно. И кстати, так никто не говорит — генератор списка. Термин хотя и имеет место быть, но малоупотребим. Лучше — списковое включение.

Comment: всмысле, вы тоже самое сказали про "генератор списка" (или это все таки я где то че-то не доглядел)

Comment: Тогда я вообще запутался

Comment: А, извините, поправил в комментарии, действительно, это я перепутал.

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = [['2', '3', '5'], ['8', '43', '3'], ['2', '1234', '12']]
print(list(map(lambda x:list(map(int,x)),lst)))
```

---

```
[[2, 3, 5], [8, 43, 3], [2, 1234, 12]]
```

Comment: Зачем такие сложности?) По-моему, в данном случае списковое включение гораздо лучше выглядит. С `map` и лямбдами код write-only.

Comment: В чем у вас возникла сложность?

Comment: Не, у меня сложность не возникла, потому что у меня есть свободные полчаса, чтобы разобраться в этом однострочнике. Если бы он был написан через списковые включения, понять (и отлаживать) его было бы значительно легче. Я ж вроде даже конкурсный вопрос на эту тему задавал.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё так можно:

```py
lst = [['2', '3', '5'], ['8', '43', '3'], ['2', '1234', '12']]
result = [list(map(int, sublist)) for sublist in lst]
print(result) # [[2, 3, 5], [8, 43, 3], [2, 1234, 12]]
```

Comment: +1 голос. Неплохой вариант. Хотя чистое списковое включение по-моему все-таки лучше.